# gets() function not working in Dev-C++

Tags: c++, c, function, dev-c++

I'm facing problems with my C algorythm that cypher a word with this function using Dev-C++.

Here is my code:

```
void cifrar(){

 int tamanhoTexto, novoASCI, caracToASCI;
 char text[129], novoTexto[129], novaLetra; 

 system("cls");
 printf("Digite a palavra a ser cifrada: ");
 gets(text); // This is not interpreted by DevC++
 tamanhoTexto = strlen(text);

 for(int i = 0; i < tamanhoTexto; i++){
       caracToASCI = text[i];
       novoASCI = decimal_octal(caracToASCI) + tamanhoTexto + i;
       novaLetra = novoASCI;
       novoTexto[i] = novaLetra;
 }

 printf("\nCifrado: %s", novoTexto);
 getch();
```

}

When I run it, the program pass the for() and set the novoTexto[] with random characters.

Thanks.

Comment: `gets` is bad to use and is depricated

Comment: read a newline that has been buffered in the stdin. try `gets(text);` --> `scanf(" %128[^\n]", text);`

Comment: `decimal_octal(caracToASCI) + tamanhoTexto + i;` is might wrong.

Comment: Well, the function should pick each letter and change to int ASCI, sum the lenght of the input word and his index in the array. Then the result should be a new int ASCI, chyphering the word. I was planning using 'gets()' cause of I was planning on a function that cypher a text with blanks spaces, but it wont works.